# How to get the output of two cat commands parallel to each other

Tags: command-line, text-processing

If I run `cat file1.txt`, I have:

```
linux mint
ubuntu
cent-os
fedora
debian
kali linux
arch linux
kubuntu
open suse
deepin
parrot os
```

Then `cat file2.txt` gives:

```
linux mint
cent-os
fedora
kali linux
arch linux
kubuntu
open
deepin
parrot
ubuntu
debian
```

But what if I want to make output like this?

```
file1.txt                      file2.txt

linux mint                     linux mint
ubuntu                         cent-os
cent-os                        fedora
fedora                         kali linux
debian                         arch linux
kali linux                     kubuntu
arch linux                     open
kubuntu                        deepin
open suse                      parrot
deepin                         ubuntu
parrot os                      debian
```

Comment: If you want to compare lines in 2 files may be you should look at the `diff` command.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you need is `paste` commad which paste rows in files side by side:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt
```

This outputs exactly what you wanted.

For more options check [`man paste`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/paste.1posix.html).

Comment: Additional info: `diff -y file1.txt file2.txt` may also be useful, displaying the differences between similar files, side by side.

Answer (score 6):

[`pr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pr.1.html) will do what you want when used like so:

```
pr -mt file1.txt file2.txt
```

- `-m` will print all files in parallel.
- `-t` will omit page headers and trailers.

Example output:

```
linux mint              linux mint
ubuntu                  cent-os
cent-os                 fedora
fedora                  kali linux
debian                  arch linux
kali linux              kubuntu
arch linux              open
kubuntu                 deepin
open suse               parrot
deepin                  ubuntu
parrot os               debian
```